# More effective way to load a std::queue<uint8_t*> with elements?

Tags: c++, queue, push, std

I am trying to find a more efficient method of loading variable length arrays of uint8_t bytes into a std::queue

The following code snippet is an attempt to reduce the actual code to something more usable as an example; so please forgive me if it's overly complex.

The code snippet works, with the exception of my inability to determine the actual length of each of the elements of the std::queue while they are still at the front of the queue. My question is, "Is there any way to push the pointer to the unsigned byte array into the queue without the intermediate step of creating a local array, copying the passed argument into it and then pushing the local pointer (See comments in code)?

```
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

std::queue<uint8_t*> _q;

void routineSubroutine(uint8_t array_a[], int size_a)
{
    /*
     * Is there anyway to push the uint8 array_a into the queue (_q) without
     * creating a new pointer to a byte array, copying the passed
     * argument into it and the pushing it?
     */

    uint8_t* a = new uint8_t[size_a];
    memcpy((void*) a, (const void*) array_a, size_a);
    _q.push(a);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    uint8_t myArray[512];

    char cfa[] = {"I wish I was at Chick-Fil-A right now"};
    memset((void*) myArray, 0x00, sizeof (myArray));
    memcpy((void*) myArray, (const void*) cfa, strlen(cfa));
    routineSubroutine(myArray, strlen(cfa));

    char five[] = {"Five Guys will do in a pinch"};
    memcpy((void*) myArray, (const void*) five, strlen(five));
    routineSubroutine(myArray, strlen(five));

    while (_q.size() > 0)
    {
        printf("Queue string value = %s\n", (char*) _q.front());
        /*
         * How do I go about determining the number of bytes in the uint8_t
         * array, whose address is at the front of the queue?
         */
        _q.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `std::queue <std::vector <uint8_t>>` would be more sensible, I would think.

Comment: Short answer: no there isn't, if you have no control over the scope of the arrays' existence. Furthermore, you should have a `std::queue` of `std::vector`s , and let `std::vector` handle all the allocations for you. Modern C++ code rarely needs to explicitly `new` or `delete` anything, and simply uses the appropriate container. And, as an extra bonus, you no longer have to worry about leaking memory.

Comment: What is surprising is that you're using `std::queue`, but totally missed using `std::vector`.  A `std::vector` is almost always the first container that a C++ programmer learns about and is encouraged to use.

Comment: *without the intermediate step of creating a local array,* -- Your code calls `new`.  That in itself could be a bottleneck.  Copying contiguous memory around can be much faster than calling the allocator each time.

Comment: The actual code has multiple threads that access the queue. Too complicated for the sample I needed to put in the example for the question. That being the case, the std::queue operations, as we used to say back in the good old OpenVMS days, are uninterruptable (at least as we understand it). The actual code receives many thousands of data grams per second and loads them into the queue. The processor element can take its time accessing the front of the queue, without waiting for synchronization elements like mutexes etc. That's the reason for the std::queue.

Comment: It isn't the queue that's in question.  It's the usage of the pointer within the queue.  You used the allocator, and that can be slower than copying contiguous bytes around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The code snippet works, with the exception of my inability to
>   determine the actual length of each of the elements of the std::queue
>   while they are still at the front of the queue

Use the proper container that knows its length/size and call the appropriate member function.  A mere pointer doesn't do that.

Here is an example of your code rewritten to use `std::vector`:

```
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::queue<std::vector<uint8_t>> _q;

void routineSubroutine(const std::vector<uint8_t>& a)
{
    _q.push(a);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char cfa[] = {"I wish I was at Chick-Fil-A right now"};
    routineSubroutine({std::begin(cfa), std::end(cfa)}); // creates a temp uint8_t vector

    char five[] = {"Five Guys will do in a pinch"};
    routineSubroutine({std::begin(five), std::end(five)}); // creates a temp uint8_t vector

    while ( !_q.empty() )
    {
        // use the `write()` function to control the number of characters
        std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(_q.front().data()), _q.front().size());
        std::cout << "\n";
        _q.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
I wish I was at Chick-Fil-A right now
Five Guys will do in a pinch
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I have full control over the type of queue I can use, while I have zero control over how the data is presented. Specifically the data is presented as a uint8_t* and size_t length. Thanks to @PaulMcKenie's example code I was able to come up with the following solution (which by the way is wicked fast):

```
std::queue<std::vector<uint8_t>> myQueue;
while(true)
{
    // Pointer (myBuffer) and length (myLength) magically appear here
    myQueue.push({myBuffer, (uint8_t*) (myBuffer + myLength)});
}
```

Problem solved.